# Can I use dynamic programming to solve this?

Tags: c, recursion, combinations, dynamic-programming

I have very little experience with dynamic programming.  I used it to solve a DNA alignment problem, a basic knapsack problem, and a simple pathfinding problem.  I understood how they worked, but it's not something I feel absolutely comfortable with yet.

I have a problem that reminds me of 0-1 dynamic programming, but the differences have thrown me off, and I'm not sure if I can still use this technique, or if I have to settle for a recursive approach.

Let's say I have a list of items, each with different values, weights, and costs.  There may be more than one of each item.

Let's say I have to choose a combo of those items which is the most valuable, but remains within the limits of weight and cost.  So far, I've described the knapsack problem, pretty much, with 2 constraints.  But here's the difference:

The value of a chosen item changes depending on how many of them I have in the combo.

Let's say that each item has a function associated with it, that tells me what a group of those items is worth to me.  It's a basic linear function, such as 
value_of_item = -3(quantity of that item) + 50

So if I have 1 of some item in a combo, then it's value to me is 47.  If I had 2 of them, then they're only worth 44 to me, each.

If I use a dynamic programming table for this, then for each cell I'd have to backtrack to see if that item is already in the current combo, making DP pointless.  But maybe there's a way to re-frame the problem so I can take advantage of DP.

Hopefully that made sense.

The alternative is to generate every combo of items, within the limits of cost and weight, figure the value of each combo, choose the most valuable combo.  For a list of 1000 items even, that's going to be an expensive search, and it's something I'd be calculating repeatedly.  I'd like to find a way to exploit the advantages of DP.

Comment: The nature of DP is to perform a calculation and then allow rapid lookup of that result for future computation.  This requires a mapping between some unique number representing the input conditions and the calculated cost for that set of conditions.  If I have 2Red and 3Green, and 4Blue, I can uniquely number all possible combinations as: r=#of red, g=#of green, b=#of blue, id = r*(3*4) + g*4 + b.  I can use id to lookup cached calculations.

Answer (score 0):

If your functions are of the form

```
value(x, count) = base(x) - factor(x) * count, factor(x) > 0,
```

then you can reduce the problem to standard knapsack by splitting the items:

```
x -> x_1 to x_max_count
value_new(x_i) = value(x, i)
weight(x_i) = weight(x)
```

Now you easily verify that no optimal solution to the new problem uses some item `x_j`, without using every `x_i` with i < j.

Proof by contradiction: Assume there is such an optimal solution S and it uses `x_j`, but not `x_i`, j > i. Then there is an alternative solution S' that uses `x_i` instead of `x_j`. Since j > i,

```
value_new(x_j) = value(x, j) 
               = base(x) - factor(x) * j 
               < base(x) - factor(x) * i
               = value(x, i)
               = value_new(x_i)
```

and therefore S' has a higher value than S and we reached a contradiction.

Furthermore, we can allow `factor(x) = 0`, this corresponds to a standard knapsack item.

However if there is a constraint of the form

```
value(x, count) = base(x) + factor(x) * count
```

where `factor(x)` is an arbitrary value, the solution above does no longer work, because the last item would be the one with the largest value. Maybe some sophisticated modification of DP may allow you to use such constraints, but I don't see any modifications of the problem itself to use DP right away.

Some research in this topic (more general):

- http://dept.cs.williams.edu/~heeringa/publications/knapsack.pdf
- http://clweb.csa.iisc.ernet.in/vsuresh/Kamesh-PLKP.pdf